# Use lightning:recordViewForm to show related record data

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-recordviewform, lightning-outputfield

I am using [lightning:recordViewForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordViewForm/documentation) with [lightning:outputField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:outputField/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleOutputField) in my lightning component.

Regular fields are shown correctly, but when I am trying to show a field of a related parent record nothing is shown:

```
<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="a1IW0000001CGSbMAO" objectApiName="Budget__c">
    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Id" />
    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Grant__c" />
    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Grant__r.Id" />
</lightning:recordViewForm>
```

[image]

As you can see - fields on the Budget__c object display good, but the Id field on the parent Grant__c object, does not display at all.

Also - on chrome dev console I get this error:

> Error: Field [Grant__r.Id] was not found

Is there something I am doing wrong or is that not supported?

Answer (score 3):

I dont believe that the correct notation is `Grant__r.Id` check the api field name on the object ad use that instead.

form Master-detail relationships (even lookups) I dont believe what you are attempting is possible, you can only reference the field itself, not the fields of the relationship object, unlike when using the [force:recordData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData/documentation) component which uses the [Lightning Data Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service.htm), versus the record:EditForm which uses the [User Interface API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_quick_start.htm)

Comment: the api field name on the object is Grant__c, I tried `Grant__c.Id` and nothing has changed

Comment: the field api name not the object, it has to be under budget.if not, you will have to create the field

Comment: This is a master detail field and it's api name is Grant__c - same as the object name

Comment: in that case i dont think what you are attempting is possible, you can only reference the master field itself, not the fields of the relationship object.

Comment: but why not - usually this is possible with change of __c to __r. I could not find any documentation that tell that it is not supported

Comment: where does it say that it is? and when you say `usually` im assuming this is when you are querying via Apex or perfomring soql's, not using this component.

Comment: for example in `force:recordData` that works

Comment: then use that component - not record:editform, it is not supported last i checked/tested

Comment: @ItaiShmida lightning:recordEditForm is for editing *a* record; unlike force:recordData, you can't access parent or child fields at all. It's not supported, any more than it would be possible to edit an account on a default Account edit page.

Comment: `Grant__c` and `Grant__r.Id` are the same thing. You can also create a formula field on the grant object to pull in the data from the related record and then display that formula field.

Comment: @sfdcfox but I do not need edit - therefore I use `lightning:recordViewForm` and not `lightning:recordEditForm`, anyway I understand that this is not possible, thanks for the help

Comment: @gNerb although they have the same value - they are not the same thing - `Grant__r.Id` takes the Id value from the parent record, and this is what I was asking if it is possible

Comment: @glls so the real answer is `NO` - you cannot use lightning:recordViewForm to show related record data. please write that in your answer and I will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

Please try this answer. What I was doing is storing the budget record in a budget attribute then using "recordViewForm" to display parent fields.

Please comment if you have any questions:

```
<aura:attribute name="budget" type="Budget__c"  />
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"  />

<force:recordData aura:id="budgetRecord" recordId="a1IW0000001CGSbMAO" targetFields="{!v.budget}" layoutType="FULL" />
<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.budget.Grant__r.Id}" objectApiName="Grant__c">
 <lightning:outputField fieldName="Id" />
<lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />                         

</lightning:recordViewForm>
```